# Split an address separated by comma

Tags: r

I have a data.frame of house sale transactions. At the moment the Address is in format.

```
  1 Accacia Avenue,This Town,This City,A10 1AA.
```

Is there a way I can split this into different columns in the data.frame removing the `,` at the same time?

I have created a separate vector for now just containing addresses.

The Address in stored in the Address column of the Dataframe - `data`.

```
head(data$Address)
[1] 22 Amesbury Road, Feltham (TW13 5HJ)
[2]Flat 11, Gloucester Court, Links Road, London (W3 0EW)
```

I need to split this into

```
"Address1", "Address2", "Address3"
```

and I also need to remove the postcode within `()` as I already have this in a separate field.

Comment: welcome to SO. You should provide a reproducible example , show what you hacve so far tried.  Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: How was the data imported? Why not use `read.csv()`?

Answer (score 3):

```
library(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(address = c("1 Accacia Avenue,This Town,This City,A10 1AA"))
separate(df , address , c("country" , "town" , "city" , "street") , ",")



# country             town      city      street
# 1 Accacia Avenue This Town This City   A10 1AA
```

these are dummy columns you can change column names as per your address

Answer (score 3):

you can also try using `splitstackshape`

```
# using df from Nader Hisham's answer

library(splitstackshape)
out = setnames(cSplit(df, "address", ","), c("country", "town", "city", "street"))

#> out
#            country      town      city  street
#1: 1 Accacia Avenue This Town This City A10 1AA
```

Comment: This could be easily done with `read.table` as well. `read.table(text= as.character(df$address), sep=',', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

For your example,

```
a  <- c("1 Accacia Avenue,This Town,This City,A10 1AA.")
```

using strsplit() as follows,

```
strsplit(a,",")
```

this gives a list which you can unlist() if you want.

```
[[1]]
[1] "1 Accacia Avenue" "This Town"        "This City"       
[4] "A10 1AA."

unlist(strsplit(a,","))

[1] "1 Accacia Avenue" "This Town"        "This City"       
[4] "A10 1AA."
```

Of course, since you have a data.frame() you will need to use lapply or sapply.  If you provide a reproducible example we can show you how the apply functions can give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way to accomplish what you need (for several reasons), but it should be fairly easy to understand.  This assumes your dataframe is named `df`, and the address strings are in a variable called `Address`.

First make sure your Addresses are stored as character strings: if `class(df$Address)` returns `"factor"` instead of `"character"`, you can convert them to character strings with

```
df$Address <- as.character(df$Address)
```

Split the addresses on the comma character:

```
df$splitAdd <- strsplit(df$Address, "\\s*,\\s*")
```

(note this assumes there may or may not be spaces around the commas that you want to drop; if there are definitely no spaces, then you can replace `"\\s*,\\s*"` with just `","`.)

Then put each of the resulting fields into a new variable, by applying to each element of the vector df$splitAdd a function that extracts the element at the appropriate index:

```
df$streetAdd <- unlist(lapply(df$splitAdd, function(x){x[1]}))
df$town <- unlist(lapply(df$splitAdd, function(x){x[2]}))
df$city <- unlist(lapply(df$splitAdd, function(x){x[3]}))
df$code <- unlist(lapply(df$splitAdd, function(x){x[4]}))
```

(You can actually probably do without the `unlist` for what you've described, but it can sometimes be more convenient.)

If you want to drop the `splitAdd` column from the dataframe:

```
df$splitAdd <- NULL
```